# Given a list of triangle vertices, how to find the neighbors for each vertex?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, algorithm

A triangle is represented by `{a,b,c}`, indicting that its vertex IDs are `a`, `b`, and `c`. A list of triangle representations, for instance, is

```
conn = {{1, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 6}};
```

I want to find the neighbors for each vertex. In this case, the results should be

```
{
    {3, 5}, (* the neighbors of vertex 1 is 3 and 5 *)
    {4, 6}, 
    {1, 4, 5}, 
    {2, 3, 5, 6},
    {1, 3, 4, 6}, 
    {2, 4, 5} (* the neighbors of vertex 6 is 2, 4 and 5 *)
}
```

I can use the `For` loop to get the results:

```
conn = {{1, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 6}};
b = Table[{}, {Max@conn}];
For [i = 1, i <= Length@conn, i++,
    {x, y, z} = conn[[i]];
    b[[x]] = Join[b[[x]], {y, z}];
    b[[y]] = Join[b[[y]], {x, z}];
    b[[z]] = Join[b[[z]], {x, y}];
];
result = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[#] & /@ b;
```

This is not efficient. Are there any elegant ways to achieve the same goal?

Comment: `Table[Union[Flatten[Select[conn, MemberQ[#, k] &]]], {k, 1, 6}]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rather like [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) for these things.

```
conn = {{1, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 6}};

Reap[Sow[#, #] & ~Scan~ conn, Union @@ conn, DeleteCases[Union @@ #2, #] &][[2, All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{3, 5}, {4, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}
> ```

A method using newer functionality:

```
Permutations /@ Rule @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ conn //
   Merge[Union] // KeySort // Values
```

> ```
> {{3, 5}, {4, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}
> ```

Or if we allow the root vertex to be included in the list of neighbors:

```
Tuples[# -> {#}] & /@ conn // Merge[Apply @ Union] // KeySort // Values
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}}
> ```

---

#### Performance

It seems that `Sow`/`Reap` is faster than my formulation with `Merge`, and both are much faster than [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is)'s brute force approach (from a comment).

```
(* J.M.'s method as a function *)
f0[conn_] := Table[Union[Flatten[Select[conn, MemberQ[#, k] &]]], {k, Union @@ conn}]

f1[conn_] := Reap[
    Sow[#, #] & ~Scan~ conn;, Union @@ conn, DeleteCases[Union @@ #2, #] &
  ][[2, All, 1]]

f2[conn_] := Permutations /@ Rule @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ conn //
    Merge[Union] // KeySort // Values


big = RandomInteger[999, {1500, 3}];

First @ RepeatedTiming[#@big;] & /@ {f0, f1, f2}
```

> ```
> {1.79, 0.00857, 0.0246}
> ```

Comment: I knew how inefficient it was, so I left it as a comment. :D BTW: it will definitely be less terse, but what happens if you replace `Map[]` with `Scan[]` in your first snippet?

Comment: @Guesswho It appears to be slightly faster, and it's probably a good practice to reduce memory usage.  I think I'll substitute it.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I had memory in mind with that suggestion (I am guessing OP will be doing heavy mesh processing with this), but I also don't know if `Map[]` is any different in the current version; hence the question.

Answer (score 5):

You could always use MMA's graph algorithms:

```
cycle = PathGraph[Append[#, First[#]]] &;    
g = GraphUnion @@ (cycle /@ conn)
```

[image]

```
AdjacencyList[g, #] & /@ Range[6]
```

> {{3, 5}, {4, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}

Sadly, it's not very efficient:

```
(g = GraphUnion @@ (cycle /@ big);
  AdjacencyList[g, #] & /@ Range[999];) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.228

Comment: Ah, I knew graphs could be used here! Nice!

Answer (score 2):

```
s = SparseArray[# -> ConstantArray[1, Length@#]] &@
    Union@Flatten[Tuples[#, 2] & /@ conn, 1];
s = s - IdentityMatrix[Length@s];
Flatten[Position[#, 1]] & /@ s
```

> {{3, 5}, {4, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}

Alternatively written:

```
SparseArray[Union @@ (Tuples[#, 2] & /@ conn) -> 1] //
 SparseArray[# - IdentityMatrix @ Length @ #]["AdjacencyLists"] &
```

> {{3, 5}, {4, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}

Comment: I added an alternative refactoring.  Be aware that both versions require the vertex list to contain only natural numbers.